# Ember JS Environment.js not updating in Chrome Extension after deployment

Tags: google-chrome, ember.js, google-chrome-extension

I have an Ember App.

I am not sure if it is related to ember-cli-chrome add-on. I don't think so.

I was successful in deploying the chrome extension on local machine. I could also see the popup loading etc.

I am printing my environment.js "config" just to see the values, and I notice that these values are not updated based on my code base. If I run the same code in normal browser instance, it works fine.

I also notice that these environment.js contents are quite old (I had deployed the extension few days back) and seems like these values are coming from there - somehow!!! I uninstalled chrome and installed it back - no luck.

What could be happening?

Thanks

Comment: Define "deployed". Is it loaded as an unpacked extension?

Comment: Okay, so looks like this was an oversight where the "meta" in the index.html should also be updated (I was creating anther chrome.html) to deploy as chrome extension and meta was not updating meta.

My bad!